# Appending label to JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

```
{title:'Alan', hasChild:true},
{title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},
{title:'Amos'},
{title:'Alonzo'},
{title:'Brad'},
{title:'Brent'},    
{title:'Billy'},    
{title:'Brenda'},   
{title:'Callie'},
{title:'Cassie'},   
{title:'Chris'},
```

This is my JSON response data, now how would i append a `Header label` to first items of each data. some thing likes which will make me differentiate that these are A, these are B.

**The changed response should look like this.**

```
  {title:'Alan', hasChild:true, header:'A'},
    {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},{title:'Alexander'},
    {title:'Amos'},
    {title:'Alonzo'},
    {title:'Brad', header:'B'},
    {title:'Brent'},    
    {title:'Billy'},    
    {title:'Brenda'},   
    {title:'Callie', header:'C'},
    {title:'Cassie'},   
    {title:'Chris'},
```

Comment: If you mean on the client side, simply iterate over the array and add attributes as you go. If not, you will need to provide more details.

Comment: That isn't JSON. It appears to be missing square brackets, has a trailing comma, has the wrong kind of quote marks around the values, and no quote marks at all around the keys.

Comment: Doesn't look like JSON to me. Also, your proposed output seems highly semantically dubious. If anything, you should have the `header` field in _each_ field, but I really don't see the point here. The information already exists: as the first letter of each `title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quoted code/markup is not [JSON](http://json.org/). (JSON requires that property names be in double quotes, and that string literals be in double quotes.) It looks like an excerpt from the middle of a JavaScript array literal, where each array entry is defined by object literals. E.g.:

```
var people = [
    {title:'Alan', hasChild:true},
    {title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},
    {title:'Amos'},
    {title:'Alonzo'}
];
```

I think in your question you've done two things between the first and second versions:

1. You've added a `header` property to first entry ("Alan") (and to "Brad" and "Callie").
2. You've added a new "Alexander" entry between "Alice" and "Amos".

If you have a reference to the array that those literals define, you can add properties (#1 above) easily enough:

```
people[0].header = 'A';
```

That creates a new property, `header`, on the object at position `0` in the array.

JavaScript also has a function for inserting into an array, called [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), that you can use to insert into an array in the middle (#2 above):

```
people.splice(2, 0, {title: 'Alexander'});
```

That says: Starting with index `2` (the "Amos" entry), remove `0` elements, then insert this one. The change is made in place.

If what you have is really a string, containing JSON, then adding to it is either a string parsing and splicing exercise, or a matter of deserializing the JSON into an object, adding the properties to the object, and re-serializing it to JSON again.

---

Here's an example of the array above in valid JSON form:

```
[
    {"title":"Alan", "hasChild":true},
    {"title":"Alice", "hasDetail":true},
    {"title":"Amos"},
    {"title":"Alonzo"}
]
```

That's as it would appear in a file stored in JSON format, or on the wire. If within a string literal in program code, of course it would need to be in the appropriate string literal form for that language, with the necessary escaping — if any — for the double quotes. For instance, that JSON as a JavaScript string literal:

```
var jsonString = '[' +
    '{"title":"Alan", "hasChild":true},' +
    '{"title":"Alice", "hasDetail":true},' +
    '{"title":"Amos"},' +
    '{"title":"Alonzo"}' +
']';
```